# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon on Application pages

Tags: ribbon, application-pages

I'm trying to create a SharePoint 2010 application page (AKA layout page) to display some information and allow users to perform some custom functionality.

I need to display custom ribbon tab for the functionality that I want to perform. And I want this custom tab to be displayed on the application page that I've created.

I've managed to create a custom ribbon tab and display it on list view ribbon through a SP feature. But how can I register this custom ribbon tab so that I will display on the application page that I've created?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

According to accomplish this, you have to create a contextual tab and 'bind' it to your page.
An example of a webpart with a contextual tab can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdeveloperdocs/how-to-create-a-web-part-with-a-contextual-tab).

In [this post](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html) MakeTabAvailable() is explained and used.

I guess it's almost the same with a page.